# What is proper order for States and territories in a dropdown list

Tags: html

My preference has always been to do Alabama through Wyoming, then Armed Forces APOs, and then territories - so that Guam is not next to Georgia.

People in the 50 states aren't likely to accidentally choose Guam over Georgia, and military and territories are used to looking down a bit to find their selection.

Is there any standard for this?  Surprisingly enough on many of the websites I go to, I can't find any good example of a dropdown for state anyway - often it's just a text field.  I have searched with no results for this.  Is there a standard protocol listed for this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's *strictly* opinion based, but it's also related to some business rule - not programming per se.

Comment: Seems the concensus is there is not a specific rule

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would recommend an alphabetical order, because in a random order, It would be difficult for anyone for find anything in a drop down without typing,  and for those who type, it doesn't matter anyways.

Perhaps in a database, you can keep a record of how many times a particular option was selected, and move the most used options to the top.